# Authentication issue with windows auth on iis8.5 server 2012

Tags: windows, authentication, iis

We have set up a webfarm with 2 IIS servers, 2 ARR servers and a network file share to hold everything.

I installed my application on the farm, set everything up and am being challenged when i go to the app.

If i move the application files to the C drive in inetpub\wwwroot folder and go directly to one of the web servers it works fine (we have some things disconnected) if i move the files back to the network share, i get challenged again.

works fine on a clone server (different name) but otherwise a copy of the two farm servers.

the network share has a sites folder with a content folder under that so \server\sites\content is the path.

I am unsure what the cause is, or how to correct it.  Any help appreciated.